# How to set slice when using PIT API w/ Spring Data Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am working on a Spring Boot application where I have to search through 100k+ docs and I am using the PIT api to achieve this. Previously, using the elasticsearch libraries this was achievable by:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
final PointInTimeBuilder pointInTimeBuilder = new PointInTimeBuilder(pitId);

SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(query);
pointInTimeBuilder.setKeepAlive(minutes);
searchSourceBuilder.pointInTimeBuilder(pointInTimeBuilder);

SliceBuilder sliceBuilder = new SliceBuilder(i, totalSlice);
searchSourceBuilder.slice(sliceBuilder);
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

RequestOptions.Builder options = RequestOptions.DEFAULT.toBuilder();
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setContentCompressionEnabled(true).build();
options.setRequestConfig(requestConfig);
SearchResponse searchResponse = this.restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest, options.build());
```

I have moved on to strictly using spring-data-elasticsearch:5.1.4 and was able to implement the PIT API by following the documentation found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.misc.point-in-time).

How can I implement this to also use slices?

[Elasticsearch PIT Api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.3/point-in-time-api.html)

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch currenlty does not support slices in queries, but you can use Spring Data Elasticsearch to create a pit, then USse a `NativeQuery` to build your query using the classes the the native Elasticsearch client provides, add the query and the pit to the `NativeQuery` from Spring Data Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there a possibility that spring-data-elasticsearch will support it in the near future? I am currently using the implementation you have mentioned but it's retrieving the same 10k docs each time and I need it to be able to iterate over 100k+ docs